# How to pass parameters to functions using applyInPandas in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe which consists of two columns. I am using a function as udf and running that function using applyInPandas in pyspark.

Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd  
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, ceil
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))
def normalize(pdf):
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=(v - v.mean()) / v.std())
df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(
    normalize, schema="id long, v double").show()
```

I have to pass one more parameter to the normalize function which acts as a udf. When I am passing a parameter I am getting an error

below is the code for that

```
import pandas as pd  
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, ceil
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))
def normalize(pdf,value):
    v = pdf.v - value
    return pdf.assign(v=(v - v.mean()) / v.std())
df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(
    normalize(1), schema="id long, v double").show()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: normalize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

How to resolve this and pass parameters to the udf using applyInPandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your `normalize` function like this:

```
def normalize_wrap(value):
    def normalize(pdf):
        v = pdf.v - value
        return pdf.assign(v=(v - v.mean()) / v.std())
    return normalize
```

Result:

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|                  v|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|-0.7071067811865475|
|  1| 0.7071067811865475|
|  2|-0.8320502943378437|
|  2|-0.2773500981126146|
|  2| 1.1094003924504583|
+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of calling the groupby function?

Answer (score 4):

Following the solution made by @domi, I'm adding the complete example for the function factory.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, ceil

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)], ("id", "v")
)


def create_normalize(value):
    def normalize(pdf):
        v = pdf.v - value
        return pdf.assign(v=(v - v.mean()) / v.std())

    return normalize


df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(create_normalize(1), schema="id long, v double").show()
```

In the example above, `create_normalize()` is a function that takes a parameter value and returns another function `normalize()` which uses this value. This returned function is what you pass into `applyInPandas()`.